# Linearlayout programtically clicked, focused and active state is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-gridview

I have an app which has a gridview with 4x4 grid. I am trying to highlight and click grid item when a cursor is on top of those grid items and cursor is controlled with a Bluetooth joystick connected with a phone.

Right now I have created a background which is like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_focus" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_normal"/>
</selector>
```

I am setting this as the background of the each grid item which is made up with Linearlayout so that I can change state when perform action programmatically.

```
public void triggerItem(int position) {
        if(gridView != null && gridView.getChildAt(position) != null)
            gridView.performItemClick(gridView.getAdapter().getView(position,null,null),position,position);
}

private void highlightItem(int position, int state) {
    if(gridView != null && gridView.getChildAt(position) != null)
        gridView.getChildAt(position).setActivated((state == 1) ? true : false);
      //  gridView.getChildAt(position).setFocused((state == 1) ? true : false);
}
```

None of the combination is working. Can anyone please tell me how can I do it or if it is possible by any means?

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out as my brother has guided me to do this --

```
    private void highlightItem(int position, int state) {
        if(gridView != null && gridView.getChildAt(position) != null) {
            gridView.getChildAt(position).setEnabled((state==1)?false:true);
            gridView.getChildAt(position).setPressed((state==1)?true:false);
        }
    }
```

And change in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/state_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/state_normal_action"/>
</selector>
```